# error in uses blue flutter and No connection

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

Despite giving the necessary permissions in the Androidmanifest and using the permission_handler, when the application is running, the Bluetooth connection request is not executed and this error is displayed. please guide me.

[image]

Comment: what all runtime permissions did you approve?